# Group Managed Service Account access to network share on remote server

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share, service-accounts, managed-service-accounts

We've got a service running using a Group Managed Service Account on a Windows Server 2016 host (HostA).

We're extending the functionality of this service so that it runs an R script which needs to access a file share `\\HostB\Data` on another Windows Server 2016 server. This is running third party R code - so it's not something we can easily change.

We've granted access to the gMSA using normal File and Storage Services - and restarted both servers just in case something was caching permissions.

However, the R call called by the gMSA to `list.files` on the HostB shared folder fails with a "file not found" error.

The same R code runs fine on my user account which has similarly configured share permissions.

Is there anything else I need to configure on the server which is sharing the folder? e.g. does the gMSA need login permission on that host? Or does that host need to be able to retrieve the password for the gMSA?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Stuart?  I'm struggling with the same thing now - the only thing I can do to get it to work is add my gMSA account to the local Administrators group on the remote server with the network share, but that seems like way more than I should need.